# Protractor: how to search in a table if the column index is unknown?

Tags: protractor

My goal is to determine if there is one row that contains a text in the column corresponding to a determined header.

Here is the view:

```
<table>
  <headers>
    <header>Age</header>
    <header hidden="isSmallScreen()">Gender</header>
    <header>Size</header>
  <headers>
  <body>
    <row>
      <col>20</col>
      <col hidden="isSmallScreen()">F</col>
      <col>180</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>21</col>
      <col hidden="isSmallScreen()">M</col>
      <col>185</col>
    </row>
  </body>
<table>
```

It is important to know that the app is responsive, meaning that if the screen is small, the second column is not in the DOM.

The test code tries to know if there is someone with size=180, and it must work whatever ther screen size.

I'm using Typescript.

```
const headers = element.all(by.tagName('header'));
let headerIndex: number;
headers.filter((header: ElementFinder, columnIndex: number) => {
        return header.getText().then(innerText: => {
            if (innerText === 'Size') {
                headerIndex = columnIndex;
            }
            return innerText === 'Size';
        });
    },
);
const rows = searchRowsByTextInColumn(headerIndex, 180);
expect(rows.count()).toBe(1);
```

The method `searchRowsByTextInColumn(headerIndex, searchText)` is implemented, no issue at that level.

The problem is the `headerIndex` that is still undefined when calling `searchRowsByTextInColumn()`. It's normal because it lies into async code.

Now how can I do to make the search work ?

Comment: You should use async / await or a callback function. Move the code for the `headerIndex` into a function and return the index once you've found it? Maybe name it `findHeaderIndex()`?

Comment: I made it work with `async/await`, many thanks @tehbeardedone.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

When `searchRowsByTextInColumn(headerIndex, 180);` be executed, the headerIndex have not been complete assign value, because `element.all().filter()` run async.

```
function findHeaderIndex(header) {
    return element.all(by.css('table > headers > header'))
         .getText().then(function(headers){
             return headers.indexOf(header);
    });
}    

function searchRowsByTextInColumn(header, cellText) {
    return findHeaderIndex(header).then(function(index) {
        var xpath = util.format('//table/body/row[ col[%s][text()="%s"] ]',
                                index, cellText);
        return element.all(by.xpath(xpath));
    });
}

searchRowsByTextInColumn('size', 180).then(function(rows){
    expect(rows.count()).toBe(1);
    // if above expect not work, try below

    rows.count().then(function(rowCount){
        console.log('rowCount: ' + rowCount);
        expect(rowCount)).toBe(1);
    });           
});
```

Comment: It seems to me that your function  `searchRowsByTextInColumn()` returns a Promise, not a `ElementArrayFinder`. It means that `rows.count()` cannot work. Am I right ? (sorry for my late answer)

Comment: Still doesn't work: `error TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<number>>'.` It seems that `expect()` only accepts promises wrapped into a Type linked to `ElementFinder`, not with plain JS promises.